# Django | Al buscar en lista columna con foreignkey devuelve error "Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Cuando se realiza una búsqueda por palabra de una columna del mismo modelo, busca bien y devuelve correctamente los resultados, pero si se busca con un nombre que corresponde a un foreignkey (en este caso se quiere buscar por "estacion" del modelo Instalacion que tiene foreignkey al modelo Station), devuelve el siguiente error:

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** Instalacion > views.py

```
class StationList(ListView):
    model = Instalacion
    template_name = 'instalacion/instalacion_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
        if name:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(estacion__icontains = name)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list
```

**Archivo** Instalacion > models.py

```
class Instalacion(models.Model):
    tipo_instalacion = models.ForeignKey(TipoInstalacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    estacion = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Instalación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Instalaciones'
        ordering = ['estacion']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.estacion) + ' - ' + str(self.tipo_instalacion)
```

**Archivo** Station > models.py

```
class Station(models.Model):
    fecha_actuacion = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha edición',null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    codigo = models.CharField('Código',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    
    objects = StationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estaciones'

    def __str__(self):
        #return  [self.name,self.area,self.codigo]
        return str(self.id) + '-' + str(self.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ser foreignkey se pone de la siguiente manera y funciona perfecto:

```
class StationList(ListView):
    model = Instalacion
    template_name = 'instalacion/instalacion_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
        if name:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(estacion__name__icontains = name)
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list
```

Lo que cambia es:

```
(estacion__name__icontains = name)
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/224683)

Comment: Lo he completado, espero que te sirva.